# Font alignment issue between Window and Mac

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

Hi I am creating a game where I uses Helvetica font for the text but there seems to have an alignment issue with the labels on different operating system - Windows and Mac os. Is there a fallback code to fix this alignment issue?

In Window: (the alignment is perfectly fine)

[Windows http://imageshack.com/a/img910/3573/3gkDL2.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img910/3573/3gkDL2.jpg)

In Mac: (the alignment of text moves up a little)

[Windows http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img912/1652/ERq9PK.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img912/1652/ERq9PK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Helvetica font is included in Windows, most likely it's rendering a different font on Windows (might be Arial, it depends on your CSS). Different fonts have different features.

My suggestion: Use a [web safe font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) for all, such as Arial, Verdana ...